# Not sure how to understand what logcat is telling me is wrong

Tags: java, android, xml, android-edittext, logcat

This is the error my logcat is giving me.  I understand it has something to do with my editText but i am not sure what.I am hopeing its a dumb mistake that can be fixed quickly and easily so i can keep working ASAP.  Help me if you can Stackoverflow Thanks!

The error only occurs when program is ran

```
02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Wicker/com.Wicker.InviteSMS}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at com.Wicker.InviteSMS.onCreate(InviteSMS.java:48)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
    02-25 16:30:19.417: E/AndroidRuntime(15259):    ... 11 more
```

This is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/contacts"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/contacts"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#fff" /> <!-- android:background="@drawable/header" for header background -->

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/contactsButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/contacts" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/enter_contact"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/contactnumber"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/to" >

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/message_to_send"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/invite_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/message_join" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendtxt"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="doLaunchContactPicker"
            android:text="@string/send_txt" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

This is the class that runs it.

```
public class InviteSMS extends Activity {

    private static final int CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT = 1001;
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = null;

    private SimpleAdapter mAdapter;

    Button btnSendSMS;
    AutoCompleteTextView txtPhoneNo;
    Button Attachment;
    Button contactsbutton;
    Button gallery;
    EditText txtMessage;

    Context context = this;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.invite_text);

        btnSendSMS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendtxt);
        txtPhoneNo = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.contactnumber);
        txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_text);
        contactsbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contactsButton);

        txtPhoneNo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        btnSendSMS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String phoneNo = txtPhoneNo.getText().toString();
                String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

                if (phoneNo.length() > 0 && message.length() > 0)
                    sendSMS(phoneNo, message);
                else
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter both phone number and message.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        });
        contactsbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent,
                        CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);

            }
        });
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
                InviteSMS.class), 0);

        String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
        String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

        PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(
                SENT), 0);

        PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,
                new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

        // ---when the SMS has been delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {
            case CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT:
                Cursor cursor = null;
                String phone = "";
                try {
                    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
                    Set<String> keys = extras.keySet();
                    Iterator<String> iterate = keys.iterator();
                    while (iterate.hasNext()) {
                        String key = iterate.next();
                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, key + "[" + extras.get(key) + "]");
                    }

                    Uri result = data.getData();
                    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG,
                            "Got a contact result: " + result.toString());

                    // get the contact id from the Uri
                    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();

                    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id },
                            null);

                    int phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

                        phone = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);

                        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "Got Contact: " + phone);

                    } else {
                        Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "No results");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Failed to get phone data", e);
                } finally {
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        cursor.close();
                    }
                    EditText phoneEntry = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_text);
                    phoneEntry.setText(phone);
                    if (phone.length() == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,
                                "No Phone Number found for contact.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }

                break;
            }

        } else {
            Log.w(DEBUG_TAG, "Warning: activity result not ok");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: The code should work as an SMS app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `ClassCastException` at this line:

```
txtMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.invite_text);
```

That means the `View` object with the id `R.id.invite_text` is not `EditText`. However this is not true since `invite_text` is indeed of type `EditText`.

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/invite_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        ...
        " />
```

So I think your resource file is not up to date. The code looks all right. Delete your `gen` folder and run it again. Your resource file should be recreated when you delete `gen` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Click the `Project` menu and choosen `Clean...` Select your project and click OK